# Recommended way to grow a Buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

Let's say I am constructing a string, or series of bytes, of variable length, in Node. The documentation for buf.write says:

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_write_string_offset_length_encoding

> Writes string to buf at offset according to the character encoding in
>   encoding. The length parameter is the number of bytes to write. If buf
>   did not contain enough space to fit the entire string, only a partial
>   amount of string will be written. However, partially encoded
>   characters will not be written.

Let's say I want to write more data than the Buffer has room for. What is the recommended way to grow it? It doesn't seem like there is a `.grow` method or similar. I can call `Buffer.from(buf)` to create a new Buffer, but that seems inefficient.

Comment: As I recall, ArrayLists that are backed by arrays deal with too many items by producing another array with double the size. It is trash for when you have to keep resizing, but it works great when you know about how big it will be.

Answer (score 11):

In case if you don't need all the contents of the whole buffer after every addition I think you can use an array of chunks (buffers) here and `Buffer.concat(chunks)` to build the whole buffer when necessary.

```
const chunks = [];

chunks.push(Buffer.from([0xE2, 0xAD, 0x90]));  // star
chunks.push(Buffer.from([0xF0, 0x9F, 0x9A, 0x80])); // rocket

const buf = Buffer.concat(chunks);

console.log(buf.toString());
```

Answer (score 7):

When the final size is not known at the beginning, you can use the approach typically applied for [dynamic arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array):

1. allocate `Buffer` with some initial size
2. write content to `Buffer` as long as there is space
3. when the next piece of content cannot fit, create a new `Buffer` with double the size, copy old buffer's content to the new buffer, and write the new content to the end as before

That way inserting at the end of the buffer can be performed in `O(1)` amortized time.

Variants of this approach are commonly used in resizable lists in [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), .NET, or e.g. in .NET's `MemoryStream` which corresponds to nodejs `Buffer`. You can see how `MemoryStream` is implemented - [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,1416df83d2368912).

Size does not necessarily have to be doubled. You can choose a different exponent, e.g. `3/2`, if you want to save some space.

Of course what is the best approach depends on your use case, but this one performs well in general.

Comment: You mean "Write content to Buffer **as long as** there is space"?

Comment: @DavidsKanal, yes I've corrected my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to change length of existing `Buffer`

> Instances of the Buffer class are similar to arrays of integers but
>   correspond to fixed-sized, raw memory allocations outside the V8 heap.
>   The size of the Buffer is established when it is created and cannot be
>   resized.

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer

However you can try to use/write some other buffer implementation or use `Buffer.concat` as Nik Markin suggests

Answer (score 1):

I am very new to Node JS, but when I tried following code it worked.
[Not sure if it creates any memory leaks or if there are any further issues...]

```
'use strict';

var tempBuffer = [];

var i = 0;

tempBuffer.push(i++);
tempBuffer.push(i++);
tempBuffer.push(i++);
tempBuffer.push(i++);
tempBuffer.push(i++);
tempBuffer.push(i++);

console.log('buf4 before creation: ');
console.log(buf4);

var buf4 = Buffer.from(tempBuffer);
console.log('buf4 after creation (type):' + typeof(buf4));

console.log('buf4 after creation (data):');
console.log(buf4);

tempBuffer.push(i++);
tempBuffer.push(i++);
tempBuffer.push(i++);
tempBuffer.push(i++);
tempBuffer.push(i++);
tempBuffer.push(i++);

buf4 = Buffer.from(tempBuffer);

console.log('buf4 after expantion (data):');
console.log(buf4);
```

And here is output:

```
buf4 before creation:
undefined
buf4 after creation (type):object
buf4 after creation (data):
<Buffer 00 01 02 03 04 05>
buf4 after expantion (data):
<Buffer 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b>
```

Comment: You literally just allocated a new Buffer (initialized from the same array, after its modification) and assigned it to the same variable name. At no point did you modify the first buffer you allocated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Nik's answer which works nicely but on some large `Buffer`s (large image bitmaps) I was running out of heap and getting errors!

I had better luck with:

```
// create instance of big enough buffer
const biggerBuffer = Buffer.alloc(smallerBufferLength + diffLen);
// copy stuff across
const count = smallerBuffer.copy(biggerBuffer);
// allow old buffer to be GC'ed
smallerBuffer = null;
```

The remaining space is by default filled with zeros: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferallocsize-fill-encoding.

:o)