# What is the JavaScript equivalent of Java's ByteArrayOutputStream?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the alternative to the following Java code for JavaScript?

```
String[] strings = {"something written here", "five", "hello world", "this is a really big string", "two words"};

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

for (String str : strings)
{
    bos.write(str.length());
    bos.write(str.getBytes());
}

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bos.toByteArray());
// send buffer somewhere...
```

I know that I can read Java's ByteBuffer sent over the network with the following JS code, but couldn't figure out a way of writing a reply using JS.

```
let strings = [];
let bytes = Buffer.from(data);

while (bytes.length > 0) {
    let size = bytes.readInt8(0) + 1;
    strings.push(bytes.toString("UTF-8", 1, size));
    bytes = bytes.slice(size);
}
```

Let's suppose I want to reply: `["hello", "how", "are you", "doing"]`

Comment: Are you asking what the equivalent of a `ByteArrayOutputStream` is, or how to send a js buffer back as a reply?

Comment: The equivalent. I know how to read but don't know how to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest equivalent to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` would probably be a [`Writable` stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) that is backed by a growing array. I guess you'll have to [implement this yourself](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_writable_stream) though, see e.g. in [Convert stream into buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19906488/1048572).

It's probably simpler to directly append buffers to an array as they come in, then [concat them all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45899032/1048572), to implement your growing buffer.

```
const strings = ["something written here", "five", "hello world", "this is a really big string", "two words"];

const output = [];

for (const str of strings) {
    const bytes = Buffer.from(str, "utf-8");
    output.push(Buffer.from([bytes.length+1]));
    output.push(bytes);
}

const buffer = Buffer.concat(output);
```

Btw I'm pretty sure you want to use `bytes.length`, not `str.length`, for your [length-prefixed strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)#Length-prefixed)? Same in your Java code, you need to use `str.getBytes().length` not `str.length()`.

Answer (score 0):

Highest Score Bergi solution is absolutely nice, but I don't get it why he has the code `output.push(Buffer.from([bytes.length+1]));`, and if I add it, it will go wrong. It will work when I remove it.